# Mapstruct 1.4.2.Final : NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

I have recently updated my spring boot version from 2.3.0.RELEASE to 2.4.4 and also updated the Map Struct version to the latest from 1.3.1.Final to is 1.4.2.Final. lombok version used - 1.18.18

But one of the mapper which was working fine with 1.3.1 is not working anymore with 1.4.2 and the scenario is as below.

**POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ......

    <properties>
        <!-- used for configuration meta data processor, please keep in sync with 
            spring boot parent version -->
        <spring-boot.version>2.4.4</spring-boot.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        .....
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ........
        ........
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ........
        ........
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>dras_mt</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        ........
                        ........
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ......
            ......
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            .....
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String plntId;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean approvalNeeded = false;
}
```

**Domain:**

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class TestDomain {
    private PlantDomain plantDomain;

    @NonFinal
    @Setter
    private SomeInfo someInfo;

    @NonFinal
    @Setter
    @Default
    private Boolean approvalNeeded = false;
}
```

**Mapper:**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { ActaulPlantMapper.class })
public interface TestEntityMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "someInfo", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(source = "plntId", target = "plantDomain")
    @Mapping(target = "approvalNeeded", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT)
    TestDomain fromEntity(TestEntity entity);    
}
```

**Generated Code with MapStruct 1.3.1**

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-03-24T11:33:38+0530",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.9.1 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
@Component
public class TestEntityMapperImpl implements TestEntityMapper {

    @Autowired
    private ActualPlantMapper actualPlantMapper;

    @Override
    public TestDomain fromEntity(WareHouseOptionEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }    
        TestDomainBuilder testDomain = TestDomain.builder();
        testDomain.plantDomain( actualPlantMapper.fromSapId( entity.getPlntId() ) );
        if ( entity.getApprovalNeeded() != null ) {
            testDomain.approvalNeeded( entity.getApprovalNeeded() );
        }
        else {
            testDomain.approvalNeeded( false );
        }    
        return testDomain.build();
    }
}
```

**Generated Code with MapStruct 1.4.2**

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-03-24T11:33:38+0530",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.9.1 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
@Component
public class TestEntityMapperImpl implements TestEntityMapper {

    @Autowired
    private ActualPlantMapper actualPlantMapper;

    @Override
    public TestDomain fromEntity(WareHouseOptionEntity entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }    
        TestDomainBuilder testDomain = TestDomain.builder();
        testDomain.plantDomain( actualPlantMapper.fromSapId( entity.getPlntId() ) );            
        testDomain.approvalNeeded( entity.getApprovalNeeded() );               
        return testDomain.build();
    }
}
```

As you see with 1.4.2 version the NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT is not applied.

I have tried with other options like putting the NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy on class level which didn't help.

Any futher inputs is highly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` was working on 1.3 is a coincidence. The strategy should only be applicable to update methods i.e. methods with `@MappingTarget`.

If you want to keep defaults as defined in your source class I would suggest using `NullValueCheckStrategy#ALWAYS`

Comment: It worked for me (it prevents overriding the value and thus default value is kept). But I don't understand why only to update methods ?

Comment: Because there is no need for MapStruct to perform any changes for freshly created objects. Update methods are different, since you might want to update something when the value is set to null